# Android: font size bigger (wider?) on HTC One than on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, user-interface, font-size

I'm using custom fonts for all components in my application. All font sizes are defined in dimens.xml file in sp format.

However fonts are bigger (wider?) on HTC ONE and smaller on Galaxy S4 which messes up my layouts. Any idea how can I correct this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my fault.

I just realized, that sp calculates font size based on user preferences.